# iceweasel (firefox) browser re-installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, package-management

I uninstalled my browser (iceweasel) from Add/Remove Software option in Kali Linux.At the time of removal it asked for one dependent package also to be uninstalled that I don't remember.

But now when I am re-installing it as per instruction given on its official  [Site](http://www.geticeweasel.org/) , it's giving the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package iceweasel is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'iceweasel' has no installation candidate
```

Any suggestions !!!

Comment: Post the command return: `apt-cache search iceweasel --names-only`.

Comment: @TiagoCA : This command gave no result.

Comment: OK, check the output of `apt-cache policy iceweasel`.

Comment: iceweasel: 
installed:(none) 
candidate: (none) 
version table:18.0.1-1 0
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 1):

[Iceweasel](https://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel) has been deprecated and replaced with vanilla Firefox, to install it use: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install firefox-esr`

Answer (score 0):

In order to correct a system with broken dependencies in place, try:

```
apt-get-f install
```

And retry:

```
dpkg --configure iceweasel
```

Comment: i have already done update & upgrade , but no effect

Comment: It's giving following error :  dpkg: error processing iceweasel (--configure):
 package iceweasel is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `config-files')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iceweasel

Comment: any other suggestion?

Comment: @wek: Sorry for the delay, check my answer.

Comment: Still no luck bro.Same error as I mentioned above :(.
If their is any way I can totally remove all package related to it and reinstall ?

Comment: =[. try `apt-get remove iceweasel` and try reinstall.

Comment: Don't you need a space after `apt-get` and before `-f`?