# how to fix source.list

Tags: linux, installation

Few days ago I tried to install the [iceweasel browser](https://superuser.com/questions/619635/iceweasel-firefox-browser-re-installation), but got no result. After searching a little I understood that there is a problem with my `sources.list`.

But now I don't know how to edit, replace or what to compare it with? How to proceed with it? I got one more [link](http://docs.kali.org/frequently-asked-questions) having entries of `sources.list` as

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Are this links useful in any sense ?

Result for cat /etc/apt/sources.list is

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 Kali - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130327-18:35]/ kali contrib main non-free
```

Comment: The contents of your `sources.list` will depend on what distribution you are using. Is this Debian? Ubuntu? Mint? Kali?

Comment: It's debian distribution

Comment: OK, Debian, not Ubuntu right? What does `grep -E "_ID|CODENA" /etc/lsb-release` return? Also,please post ([edit] your question, do not answer with a comment) the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: grep: /etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory. How to see source.list content I don't know.Please can you give a command for it

Comment: Hey I am using kali OS but I think its based on debian

Comment: OK, kali is not Debian, it is just based on it. It is also a really really bad distribution for a newbie, why are you using it? Anyway, to see your `sources.list` run `cat /etc/apt/sources/list`.

Comment: cat: /etc/apt/sources/list: No such file or directory

Comment: you mean to say source.list? you have written source/list

Comment: Result for cat /etc/apt/sources.list is   deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130327-18:35]/ kali contrib main non-free

Comment: Yes,sorry I meant `.list`. But please, as I said, do not answer in comments, update your question, comments are hard to read and the information gets lost.

Comment: Sorry fot that.edited above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Kali FAQ you linked to, your `sources.list` should contain exactly whatyou have posted. Follow these steps to make it so:

1. Open a terminal and run

   ```
   sudo gedit `/etc/apt/sources.list`
   ```

   I am not sure if `gedit` is installed by default. Apparently, Kali uses `gvim` as its default editor, if you know how to use `vim` and `gedit` is not installed, replace `gedit` with `gvim` in the command above. If you don't know how to use `vim`, try `nano` instead.
2. Edit the file so that its contents are:

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
   deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
   deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 Kali - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130327-18:35]/ kali contrib main non-free
   ```
3. Save the file, close the editor and run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. You should now be able to install `iceweasel` with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install iceweasel
   ```

I must stress that if you don't know how to do these things, Kali is not the right distribution for you. You should consider switching to something else.

Comment: But every distribution will have some or the other problem.I picked this because I want to learn security.And on one of the another form one guy suggested me something like you do but with more links.Here is the [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83202/iceweasel-firefox-browser-re-installation/83232?noredirect=1#comment123412_83232).Can you suggest me if this is right.

Comment: @wek yes, every distribution has different problems. You are using a distribution that is targeted at expert users, this is really not a good lace to start. You can learn about security using ANY Linux, Kali is not designed to help you learn, it assumes you already do. Why don't you have a look at Mint or Ubuntu or any of [these](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?category=Beginners)? As for the other answer, it is the same idea, I gave you the minimal version, both are correct.

Comment: Thanks very very much terdon. Yes you are right,I will switch to Ubuntu first.I am kind of lazy guy and avoid to install all the security softwares . So I choosed this distribution.I will inform you if its a sucess.You helped me a lot. :)

Comment: You're very welcome (remember to accept my answer and the one on U&L if we answered your question).

Comment: Thanks a lot terdon.I finally fixed it with your guidance.however it took 2 hrs to fix 13 MB software.What is U&L.

Comment: U&L is Unix and Linux stack exchange, the site where you posted your other question. By the way, [cross posting is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101), try not pto ost the same question on multiple stack exchange sites.

Comment: Ok will keep in mind